# jqxTree inside jqxExpander without fixed sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqxwidgets

So basically I have a jqxSplitter as a container with fixed sizes. On the left side should be 2 jqxExpanders of which the lower one should contain a jqxTree.
This works so far except:

As I set the Height of the second expander to 100% it expands above the borders of the Splitter. I cant use auto for its size since then the Tree won't show.

So, how can I make the second expander use all the remaining space, without going off borders?

Heres my code so far, its quite long, but only because I gave the tree a lot of items to check scrollbar behavior, i figure I just let it in if you want to try it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxsplitter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxexpander.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxtree.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                 // Create jqxSplitter
                $("#jqxSplitter").jqxSplitter({
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 500
                });
                 // Create jqxExpanders
                $("#jqxexpander1").jqxExpander({ 
                    width: 'auto', 
                    height: 'auto'
                 });

                $("#jqxexpander2").jqxExpander({ 
                    width: '100%', 
                    height: '100%',
                    initContent: function () { 
                        // Create jqxTree
                        $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
                            width: '99%',
                            height: '99%'
                        });
                    }
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='jqxSplitter'>
            <div>
                <div id='jqxexpander1'>
                    <!--Header-->
                    <div>
                        Header</div>
                    <!--Content-->
                    <div>
                        Content
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='jqxexpander2' style="bottom: 0px">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <div>
                        Header</div>
                    <!--Content-->
                    <div>
                        <div id='jqxTree' style="border-style: none">
                            <ul>
                                <li>User
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Info
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>Info 1</li>
                                                <li>Info 2</li>
                                            </ul>   
                                        </li>
                                        <li>Documents
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                            </ul> 
                                        </li>
                                        <li>More Documents
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>Document 1</li>
                                                <li>Document 2</li>
                                                <li>Document 3</li>
                                                <li>Document 4</li>
                                                <li>Document 5</li>
                                                <li>Document 6</li>
                                                <li>Document 7</li>
                                                <li>Document 8</li>
                                                <li>Document 9</li>
                                                <li>Document 10</li>
                                                <li>Document 11</li>
                                                <li>Document 12</li>
                                                <li>Document 13</li>
                                                <li>Document 14</li>
                                                <li>Document 15</li>
                                                <li>Document 16</li>
                                                <li>Document 17</li>
                                                <li>Document 18</li>
                                                <li>Document 19</li>
                                                <li>Document 20</li>
                                                <li>Document 21</li>
                                                <li>Document 22</li>
                                                <li>Document 23</li>
                                                <li>end</li>
                                            </ul> 
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle.net and link it from your question?

Comment: I didn't know about jsfiddle, but from what I saw I guess I can't since it doesn't support the jqWidgets library.

Comment: You can add arbitraty external resources (CSS & JS).